# `AutoFillTextBox type is not resolvable` why?

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, autofill

I have created a `comboBox`in JavaFx program and I have populated. But Since , there are too many options to be chosen I thought I need to make the user experience more convenient by allowing the them to insert what they're looking for and get it faster in case that options exists . My google search led me to `AutoFillTextBox` .The problem is once I want to use it , it says the type is not defined . Even though I have imported `import java.util.*;`

Any Idea what am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import np.com.ngopal.control.AutoFillTextBox;
```

The problem you are facing seems to be that AutoFillTextBox is not specified in import java.util.*; It is a jar file you have to download:

http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/07/04/autofill-textbox-with-filtermode-in-javafx-2-0-custom-control/